# Proper way to apply selector to jquery object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So most examples I've seen of jQuery selectors are like this:

```
$('#example tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').css('display', 'none');
```

But what if I already have this:

```
var exampleTable = $('#example tbody');
```

How do I properly apply ... `tr td:nth-child(1)').css('display', 'none');` to `exampleTable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) at this context since it is used to look for descendant elements,

```
var exampleTable = $('#example tbody');
exampleTable.find('tr td:nth-child(1)').hide();
```

And as a side note, use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) instead of `.css('display', 'none');`

Comment: What's the difference between `.hide()` and `.css('display', 'none')`?

Comment: @dotnetN00b Both will do the same thing.. But using `.hide()` will make your code more readable and even you can animate the hiding process by passing parameters into it. Please read the provided Doc link.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific example, with [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
exampleTable.find('tr td:nth-child(1)').hide();
```

In general, using one or more of the [tree traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) (there's a whole lot of them).

Answer (score 1):

and yet another way to do it:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(1)',exampleTable).hide();
```